# Extract One page of a complex application

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, web

We at our company have a complex Angular Typescript Less Application. For demo purposes I need to extract one page of the application. This is very hard, since we have so many services, controlles, Less and CSS-Files which have dependency to that page.
What would be the easiest way to do that, to only get the used Javascript and CSS?

EDIT: The page is actually a styleguide which needs to get distributed and normalized. So I don't want to forward the whole application source-code, just one html-file with one Javascript (where only the code which is needed is inside it) and only the used CSS. This would be best-case. I know it's hard to accomplish but maybe there's some kind of trick.

EDIT2: Okay I thought it was clear what I want to do, so here again:

I have a Webproject with various pages (Well kind of pages, since it's Angular and they are only templates). So now I want to exclude/extract one page out of this project, so it can be viewed locally, just that one page. When I am on that page in Chrome and click save, it downloads me the HTML. But of course this is useless, since all of the Javascript and CSS is missing.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract" ? You couldn't just redirect to the wanted page ?

Comment: I added some information

Comment: Hard to make any sense out of this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you could use Gulp to make a extract task to inject css and js in our html page

Source : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject